# Carbon DateTime is Diffrent between testing and Controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I tested carbon date Time different between testing and Controller printing.

```
   /** @test */
   public function personal _plan_expire_time_rest()
   {

   $user = \App\Models\User::factory(['expired_at' => Carbon::now()->addDays(365)]);
// dump($user->expired_at); //result is 2022-08-01
// $user->update([
//    'expired_at' => $user->expired_at->addDays(30)
// ]);
// dump($user->expired_at); //result is 2022-08-30
// $user->update([
//    'expired_at' => $user->expired_at->subDays(30)
// ]);
// dd($user->expired_at); //result is 2022-08-01

     $this->get('/show-user')->assertStatus(200);
  }
```

Here is I test result in Controller

```
function show() {             
   dd($subscription->user->expired_at); //result is 2022-08-30
   dump($subscription->user->expired_at->subDays($subscription->order->duration));  //result is 2022-07-31             
}
```

So, when I print controller function, result should be **2022-08-01** but controller function is still **2022-07-31**

config/app.php is 'timezone' => 'UTC',

So, I would like to know why datetime is different?

Comment: It is a conflict between your server Time. Configure yours by specifying your city.  And accurate time on your Server.

Answer (score 1):

As Tayyab mehar mention in the comments the problem is that the server time isn't the same as you timezone. I think you can fix this by adding a setTimezone from Carbon, so when you save your data it will get your current timezone regardless of the one setup in your config file so the call will look something like this:

```
Carbon::now()->addDays(365)->setTimezone(You Timezone here)
```

You can get a list of all php timezone here [php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Also in my projects I use [this package](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip) that gives you specific timezone based on your IP so the above call will look something like

```
Carbon::now()->addDays(365)->setTimezone(geoip(Request::ip())->timezone)
```